# How To: Flipboard Navigation Animation (Not the Page Flip)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Note: I'm Not asking about the page flip animation.

I'm very much interested in making a similar flipboard navigation animation. (see the attached screenshot). The old view would sink and disappear while the incoming view would slide from right to center

Is there any github repo or code snippet that I should take a look at?

[image]

Comment: I redid UINavigationController to do something like that.  Very easy.

Comment: @CodaFi can you elaborate? Thanks a million.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/github/twui/blob/master/lib/UIKit/TUINavigationController.m) what I based my implementation on.  You will have to port this to UIKit (the easy part), then create a category on UIViewController so you can access the navigation controller for pushing and popping.  Modify the `pushViewController:animated:` method to use your own animation

Answer (score 1):

Found this in github after long search. https://github.com/dingtianran/DTRNavigationController

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking https://github.com/michaelhenry/FlipBoardNavigationController